# Remove Spinner animation Boostrap / JS

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to remove spinner animation after showing results.

```
<script>
var url = "TEST";
$(document).ready(function () {
    document.getElementById('spinner').setAttribute('style', 'display:none')
    $("button").click(function () {
        document.getElementById('response').setAttribute('style', 'display:none')
        var searchText = document.getElementById('searchText').value;
        var countryCode = document.getElementById('countryCode').value;
        $('#btn').html('<span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm mr-2" role="status" aria-hidden="true" id"loading"></span>En cours...').addClass('disabled');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: {
                'query': searchText,
                'country_code': countryCode
            },
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                document.getElementById('response').setAttribute('style', 'display:block')
                document.getElementById('spinner').setAttribute('style', 'display:none');
                create_response(response);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                document.getElementById('spinner').setAttribute('style', 'display:none');
                document.getElementById('btn').setAttribute('style', 'display:block');
                alert('Error! Try again..');
                console.log(data);
            },
        });
    });

});
```

```
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center"><button id="btn" class="btn btn-primary" >Extraire</button></div>
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center"><button id ="spinner" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" disabled>
  <span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  En cours...
</button>
```

Spinner is still showing after results. I don't know how to restore button.

Please note that some code has been deleted.

Thank you for your help

Comment: You are using an odd combination of vanilla JS and jQuery, generally it's better to pick one and stick with it for consistency. Also, there's a typo where you set the html: `id"loading"` is missing an `=`

Comment: You're looking for id="spinner" which doesn't exist from what I see. The id I see = "loading." However, the HTML you provided doesn't have any ID property.

Comment: Full code is available here : https://www.amzacademy.fr/amazon-autocomplete-extractor

Answer (score 0):

You need to restore the state of your button to the way it was before you added the spinner.

```js
<script>
var url = "TEST";
$(document).ready(function () {
    document.getElementById('spinner').setAttribute('style', 'display:none')
    $("button").click(function () {
        document.getElementById('response').setAttribute('style', 'display:none')
        var searchText = document.getElementById('searchText').value;
        var countryCode = document.getElementById('countryCode').value;
        $('#btn').html('<span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm mr-2" role="status" aria-hidden="true" id"loading"></span>En cours...').addClass('disabled');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: {
                'query': searchText,
                'country_code': countryCode
            },
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                $('#btn').html('Extraire').removeClass('disabled');
                create_response(response);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                $('#btn').html('Extraire').removeClass('disabled');
                alert('Error! Try again..');
                console.log(data);
            },
        });
    });

});
</script>
```

Also the `disable` class isn't preventing your button from being used, not sure if that is intentional or not.

To properly disable a button use the following code:

```js
$('#btn').attr("disabled", true);
```

Set the value to false again when you are finished with loading the results (or when there is a error).